# Proof of "non-existence" of marginals of the Husimi $Q$-function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform, deformation-quantization

There are many ways to consider the Husimi ($Q$) quasi-probability distribution function, e.g. as the expectation of the density operator in a coherent state or as the Weirstrass transform of the Wigner function. I am going to use the "measurement" of a wavefunction by a coherent state *(I will drop all normalization constants for simplicity)*:

$$
Q(x_0, k_0; \sigma) = |\left\langle \psi | \mathcal{C}(x_0, k_0; \sigma) \right\rangle |^2
$$

where the coherent state is parameterized by $\sigma$ (squeezed state), where 
$$
\left\langle x | \mathcal{C}(x_0, k_0; \sigma) \right\rangle = 
e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2}{4\sigma^2}}e^{ik_0x}
$$
in position representation.

In my studies about quasi-probability distributions of wavefunctions, I have encountered the statement:

> The $Q$ function does not allow calculating the *marginals* i.e. integrating over one of the phasespace variables to get the full distribution function of the other one, unlike the Wigner function
>   or some similar variant. For example: the book "Quantum Optics in Phasespace" by Wolfgang Schleich, chapter 12.

When calcuating Husimis of a given wavefunction, I can always see this statement and make sense out of it. For example, the Husimi function of a plane wave $P = \exp(ikx)$ can be straightforwardly calculated,
$$
Q_P(x_0, k_0; \sigma) \propto \sigma^2 e^{-(k-k_0)^2\sigma^2}
$$

It is immediately clear that the marginal over $x_0$ makes no sense here.

**Question: Is there a general proof, or some intuitive way to understand why the marginals do not make sense for *any* wavefunction?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stuff is all in [Husimi's original 1940 paper](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Husimi40.pdf), but you have to work at it... So I'll just illustrate the point based on our [concise summary](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf) of the material in Wolfgang's outstanding treatise, eqns (1) and (122) here. I'll ignore normalizations, and worse yet, I'll set $\hbar=1$ and $\sigma=1/4$ to drive the qualitative point home.

So the [Husimi *Q* is a Gaussian smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation),  Gaussian low-pass filtering, or Weierstrass transform of the Wigner function *f*,
$$
f(x,p)\propto \int\! dy~\psi^* \left (x- 
y \right )~e^{-i2yp} ~ \psi \left (x+  y \right ) ,\\
 Q(x,p)=T(f)= \exp \left({ 1\over 4}(\partial_x^2
           +\partial_p^2 ) \right) f     \\
 \propto \int dx' dp' 
\exp \left( -{(x'-x)^2-(p'-p)^2   } \right) ~ f(x',p') .  
$$

Consequently, the *p* marginal of *Q* is a quadruple integral,
$$
\int dp ~ Q(x,p)\propto \int dp dy dp'dx'  ~ e^{   -{(x'-x)^2-(p'-p)^2   }  } ~e^{-i2yp'} ~  \psi^* \left (x'- 
y \right )\psi \left (x'+  y \right ) .
$$
One can now leave *p'* alone, and shift *p* by *p'*, and do the unlinked Gaussian integral in *p*. *Then* do the integral in *p'* to obtain a *δ(y)*,
which then collapses the *y* integral, to yield a mere Weierstrass transform of the space probability density,
$$
\int dp ~ Q(x,p)\propto\int dx' ~ e^{   - (x'-x)^2  } \psi^* \left (x'  
  \right )\psi \left (x'  \right )=  \int dx' ~ e^{   - (x'-x)^2  } \rho(x'), 
$$
so, clearly not a probability density, unless *ρ* is an  eigenfunction of *T*, [so a Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform#Transforms_of_some_important_functions). This is in sharp contrast to $\int\! dp ~f(x,p)=\rho(x)$.

The evident intuitive visualization of this is that (even though it is positive semidefinite) the Husimi *Q* is not a plain phase-space probability measure for functions, but must be star-multiplied with them to yield expectation values . And, unlike the Wigner-Moyal product $\star$, the Husimi star product, $\circledast$ (124) in our summary,  cannot be entirely integrated by parts out of the integral$\langle {{\mathfrak G}}\rangle = \int\! dx dp~ g(x,p) 
\exp\!\left(-{\hbar\over 4}(\partial_x^2+\partial_p^2 ) \right)  Q(x,p)$: it will emphasize and de-emphasize parts of Q and the observable which only exceptional visualizers  can intuit. This is the best illustration of the elusive picture the Husimi provides for intuiting *where* the action is probability-wise.

Comment: I think the last equation of your answer is more than strong enough to convince me. I also appreciate the extra last paragraph and the reference to your concise summary!

Comment: OK, thanks. If it is not a digression, I added a couple of formulas to make it more explicit.

Comment: Just one final question regarding the Weirstrass transform of $f$. In the case where one wants to use squeezed states (the *generalized* transform), then I would guess that the exponentials $\exp(-(x'-x)^2 -(p'-p)^2)$ would *not* have equal factors; the second would have $\sigma^2$ and the first $1/\sigma^2$?

Comment: To answer my own comment: **yes**. The answer is also in the paper "Wigner and Husimi Functions in Quantum Mechanics" by Kin'ya Takahashi.